# Magento 2: How to check if order is not created but payment is deducted

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order, place-order, deadlock

I have a situation on which sometimes deadlock occurs during order place.
But the order is not getting placed and order payment is done successfully.

So to overcome that issue, I am using `sales_order_payment_place_end` event to check which is working fine till the payment is deducted, but I order entity is not created using this event. So I am not able to check the situation because of it.

And due to deadlock issue this `sales_order_place_after` event is not able to trigger.

I just want to send an email if order is not created in Magento but payment is deducted

Any solution for this situation?

**Below is the code I am using:**
**app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/events.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <!--Start: Send email if Payment Received for Unplaced Order-->
    <event name="sales_order_payment_place_end">
        <observer name="order_not_place_email_alert" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\FailedOrderEmail"/>
    </event>
    <!--End: Send email if Payment Received for Unplaced Order-->
</config>
```

**app/code/Vendor/Module/Observer/FailedOrderEmail.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Model\Order;
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Translate\Inline\StateInterface;

class FailedOrderEmail implements ObserverInterface
{
    const EMAIL_TEMPLATE = 'order_not_placed_template';

    protected $transportBuilder;
    protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        StateInterface $inlineTranslation
    ) {
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->inlineTranslation = $inlineTranslation;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend_Log_Writer_Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
        $logger = new \Zend_Log();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);

        /** @var Order $order */
        $payment = $observer->getEvent()->getPayment();
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getPayment()->getOrder();
        
        $logger->info('Payment Data');
        $logger->info(json_encode($payment->getData()));
        $logger->info('Payment Status Pending');
        $logger->info(json_encode($payment->getIsTransactionPending()));
        $logger->info(json_encode($payment->getIsFraudDetected()));
        $logger->info('Order Data');
        $logger->info(json_encode($order->getData()));


        // Here I just load the order but order is not created yet, so how I have to check that order is created or not
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $orders = $objectManager->get(\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface::class)->loadByIncrementId($order->getIncrementId());
        $logger->info('Full Order Data');
        $logger->info(json_encode($orders->getData()));

        // if ($order->getState() == Order::STATE_NEW && $order->getStatus() == Order::STATE_NEW) {
            $this->inlineTranslation->suspend();
            // Prepare email template variables
            $templateVars = [
                'customer_name' => $order->getCustomerFirstname(). " ".$order->getCustomerLastname(),
                'order_id' => $order->getIncrementId(),
                'allowed_to_send' => '1'
            ];

            $logger->info('Template Vars');
            $logger->info(json_encode($templateVars));

            // Set sender information
            $senderInfo = [
                'name' => $this->scopeConfig->getValue('trans_email/ident_general/name', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE),
                'email' => $this->scopeConfig->getValue('trans_email/ident_general/email', ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE),
            ];

            $logger->info('Sender Info');
            $logger->info(json_encode($senderInfo));

            // Set recipient
            $recipientEmail = 'abc@gmail.com';

            // Load and send email template
            $transport = $this->transportBuilder
                ->setTemplateIdentifier(self::EMAIL_TEMPLATE)
                ->setTemplateOptions(['area' => \Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_FRONTEND, 'store' => \Magento\Store\Model\Store::DEFAULT_STORE_ID])
                ->setTemplateVars($templateVars)
                ->setFrom($senderInfo)
                ->addTo($recipientEmail)
                ->getTransport();
            
            $logger->info('transport');
            // $logger->info();

            $transport->sendMessage();
            $this->inlineTranslation->resume();
        // }
    }
}
```